# Insert into mysql multiple input data that are created with a jquery add_function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, sql

I have the following html:

```
<h4>Add Steps</h4>
<ul id="pasi">
 <li>
<span>Pasul 1: </span><textarea id="pas"></textarea>
<input  id="add_pas" type="button" value="Add Step" onclick="add_pas()"/>
 </li>
<input id=""  type="button" value="Add recipe" />
```

and this jquery function:

```
    function add_pas() {
var pas = "Pasul " + i;
var list = $('#pasi');
var html = "<li class='pas-"+ pas +"'><span>" + pas + "</span><textarea></textarea><img src='../images/x.png' /></li>";

list.each(function(){
    $(this).append(html);
    });
    i++
}
```

The function adds a new step when the button is clicked.

SQL:

```
    TABLE recipe_steps (id, recipe_id,sort_oder,description)
```

My question is how do I insert the custom number of steps into the database, and then how to retrieve it.
  A first thaught was to insert all the steps into a vector(steps[]) but I don't really know where to start.
  Please take in consideration that I'm a begginer in php, mysql, jquery .
Thank you and I hope I made it as clear as possible.

Comment: if you give each  textarea a  `name` when the page is submitted you can process it like any other form

Comment: The same name for all the textareas or a different one for each of them?

Comment: each should be different, an easy approach would be `<textarea name='mytext[]'>` then you have a nice a array to work with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with this that worked

```
 function trimite(){
var pasi = {};  //initializing an array
var k=0;
$(".nimic").each(function () {  //class of the <textarea>
    pasi[k]=$(this).val();  //takes the value for each of the textareas created
    k++;
});


$.ajax({ // sends all the textarea created to the php processing script
    type:'POST',
    url:"functions/add_recipe.php",
    dataType:"json",
    data:{
        'pasi':pasi
    },
    success: function(data){

    },
    error: function(){
        alert('error');
    }
});

return false;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand how you're transitioning from js to inserting into SQL (but I may just be missing something!), but IMO you should use a jquery $.post function to call a separate .php file to do the insertion

```
$("#FORM_SUBMIT_ID").click(function() {
    $("#ENTIRE_FORM_NAME").submit( function () {    
          $.post(
           'SQL_INSERTION.PHP', //NOTE <-- assumes .php file is in same dir as curr file
            $(this).serialize(), //This takes your form and auto separates it
            function(data){
              $("#ERRORS").html(data); //This will append error text to a div if you wish
            }
          );
          return false;   
        }); 
});
```

Then, on your .php file you will have an array in $_POST with ALL the form values that were filled out. To test how serialize() formats your form into an array, on your php file just write

```
<?php print_r($_POST); ?>
```

I believe that should be enough. Then from there, for custom insertion, depending on how many values you have that can vary in presence, simple if/else if statements may be good enough.

i.e. if ($_POST['name']){ //code}

Alternatively, you can pass in a form "type" along with the serialized data to .php, and that will go into the $_POST array.

Comment: I forgot to mention I will be sending the values trough ajax into a php processing script. I'try this tomorow and see how it works. Thx

Comment: I don't know why but the code only sends 2 inputs from the form. Anyway I came up with another solution.